How to stop the second console.log from including the array of the first in its calculations?
I made a function that will find the sum of whatever array you put in. The problem is that if I have 2 of these console.log up, the second will add the sum of the first to it's result. What am I doing wrong?


let sum = 0;

function getAverage(scores) {
  for (let i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
    sum += scores[i];
  }
  return sum
}

console.log(getAverage([92, 88, 12, 77, 57, 100, 67, 38, 97, 89]));
console.log(getAverage([45, 87, 98, 100, 86, 94, 67, 88, 94, 95]));



The first is 717, the second should be 854, but it added the results of the first to get 1571.

move let sum = 0 inside the function - by the way, your function is poorly named as it returns a total, not an average

This is because the sum variable that you have defined is outside the function getAverage and it is not reset when you are calling the function.
Either you can declare the variable inside the function so that it will create a new variable every time the function is invoked.
Alternately you can also use reduce


function getAverage(scores) {
  return Array.isArray(scores) && scores.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr, 0)
}

console.log(getAverage([92, 88, 12, 77, 57, 100, 67, 38, 97, 89]));
console.log(getAverage([45, 87, 98, 100, 86, 94, 67, 88, 94, 95]));




Thank you for your help. I can't upvote your answer but it was correct.

I'm not sure if let the function silently fail and return false when scores is not an array was a good idea...
